# When is it OK to use stranded wires in fixed installation?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have heard many times that fixed installation requires single core wires while the flexible stranded wires are designed for movable devices like vacuum cleaners and TVs.

I know that a stranded wire has two primary disadvantages compared to a solid core wire:

- It is more prone to oxidation (due to larger surface area for the same cross-section area), making it inferior for permanent installation.
- It is thicker for the same cross-section area.

However recently I saw in Spain that professional electricians were installing stranded 240 V wires in a commercial building. This made me wonder if what I had heard before was outdated or I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

All wire sizes are available in stranded, however not all cabling styles are made with stranded wire (i.e. NM/Romex). Any sort of flexible cordage is only stranded.

For single-wire 10-12-14 gauge THHN/THWN as is widely used in commercial work, they sell both kinds right next to each other - watch out what you buy.  I use exclusively stranded.

Larger wiring sizes are not available in solid, because they are impossible to bend.

You can use stranded wire anytime you can get it, and your terminations are listed for stranded wire. For instance a backstab (push-in) connector might be listed for ”14 AWG solid" in which case they mean "not stranded".

Comment: I think stabs should be outlawed. They have been the top failure I have been called to repair by at least a factor of 10. A back and side outlet or switch take stranded and no ferule or fork compression fitting is needed for most of them.

Comment: According to the NEC  wire larger than #8 installed in a raceway has to be stranded. 310.106(C) Stranded Conductors. Where installed in raceways, conductors 8 AWG and larger, not specifically permitted or required elsewhere in this Code to be solid, shall be stranded.

Comment: Maybe there is some US/Europe difference. Neither in our DIY stores, nor on German Amazon can I find the stranded wires intended for outdoor or in-ground installation. While I can try to use a stranded cable that _is_ sold, these mentioned types are not available in stranded versions at all.

Comment: On the other hand, I've found some German forum thread where the same question is asked, and no reason besides cost and thickness is given for not using a stranded cable in the walls.

Answer (score 1):

First off wires can be broadly divided into (at least) four categories.

- Solid core: One single wire, commonly used at smaller sizes for fixed wiring)
- "stranded": Split into a relatively small number of coarse strands, commonly used for larger fixed wiring cables, and/or for wiring that will be pulled into conduits.
- "Flexible": split into smaller strands, used for appliance cords and such.
- "extra flexible": split into strands so small you can't really see them, used in specialist applications like test leads.

The biggest downside of higher strand counts is cost, it costs more to draw out the wire into finer strands and then to combine those strands back together into a core.

Secondly regulations and/or accepted standards* for fixed-wiring in bulidings are something that varies a lot. Even within the normally pro-harmonisation EU there is a lot of variation.

"stranded" conductors are commonly used in fixed-wiring, but normally only at larger sizes or where individual conductors are pulled into conduits. For smaller sized cables solid conductors are sufficiently flexible and are cheaper to make so they are what gets made.

Some countries are very prescriptive about what types of cable can be used in fixed-wiring. Others leave more up to the judgement of the installer. Ultimate a question of what cables you can/should use cannot be answered outside the context of a country. It can also depend on what device you are terminating to, some types of connection are not suitable for fine-stranded conductors.

* Sometimes the law doesn't specifically mandate a particular standard, but nevertheless there is an accepted standard that electricians normally work to.

Comment: You can get stranded wires in some cable constructions (TC, MC) in typical general branch circuit sizes

Comment: I presume your comment was reffering to north american cable types.

Thinking about it much the same is true over here in the UK, SWA cable is usually stranded even at small sizes.

Comment: Yeah -- UK SWA cable is equivalent to US AC or MCI-A cable more or less

Answer (score 0):

Larger wiring is stranded, but uses thicker strands then flexible appliance leads

small (lesser cross-sectional area and current-carrying capacity) E.g. as used in lighting circuits.

[image]

large (greater cross-sectional area and current-carrying capacity) E.g. as used in circuits to electrical outlets, electric ovens etc.

[image]

The above are both "twin & earth" wiring for fixed installation (in the wall) as used in the UK. Products and regulations in your locale may vary.

Note that these differ from typical stranded wires used in appliance leads. Those typically use much finer strands.

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware there were two varieties of stranded wires. So when can I use a stranded installation wire instead of the solid core wire? Are there guidelines? And how can I distinguish the two stranded wire types when shopping?

Comment: Usually, it's simply what's available/manufactured. Where I am, 1mm^2 tends to be solid, 1.5mm^2 has 3 or 7 strands depending on the manufacturer, and 2.5mm^2 or larger usually has 7 strands.

Comment: While NM and AC or MC are typically solid wires at lighting circuit sizes -- nothing stops you from wiring your whole house with stranded THWN in conduit.

Comment: I agree +, stranded wire is less prone to breaking at the strip point. You see almost no solid wire in an industrial facility even down to the control wire at 16 & 18 gauge.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel which has its advantages.  It's worth doing at least in certain places, and you can mix and match.

Comment: I cannot find the cables as depicted in Europe.

Comment: Nor in the US... kinda. Those pictured cables, we call that NM (non-metallic). 8 AWG and up (3,2mm) is only *legal* in stranded.  10 AWG and below (2,5mm) is only *available* in solid. The latter is used for almost all outlet and lamp wiring (what the UK calls loops) but only in residences. Commercial doesn't generally use NM and uses either stranded or solid single wires.  In these photos grounds are smaller.  In the US that is not allowed in <=10 AWG outlet and lamp wiring.

Comment: Pretty much the same in the UK, 4mm² and up T&E is stranded, 2.5mm² and down T&E is solid. I think in theory you can special-order smaller sizes of T&E in stranded but in practice noone does.